# how to solve "/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: no such file or directory" error

Tags: installation, 12.10, networking, drivers, atheros

I installed ubuntu 12.10 64 bit on my desktop **HP Elite 7500**, but I have no ethernet connection.  I have an Atheros ethernet card is. I have downloaded drivers to install. I extracted files. When I try to install it, it gives :

```
/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: no such file or directory
```

What is the problem.

I googled found some sites where some people tell to install kernel headers, but if I  have no network and an internet so how can I download and install it.

Another interesting thing is that, when I try to install driver from Live-CD it installed and I connected to the network. Then what is the problem, when I try to do this from installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

if the Internet is working fine using a LiveCD, first boot through the LiveCD. Then, mount your Ubuntu installed driver in any directory.

steps : 1) go to ubuntu.com 2) download any ubuntu (32bit is preferable ) 3) then copy it to any cd or dvd and copy to the usb stick using a unet boot tool 4)and then boot your system with live OS

so as you have mentioned in your question in live os network will work and once you have boot to live os check weather you are connected to internet

NEXT STEP :

sudo cat /proc/partions

This command will tell you all the partions which you have Now you need to find in which partion you have installed ubuntu

say for eg : the output of cat /proc/partions is this:

8 0 78150744 sda 8 1 3998720 sda1 8 2 1 sda2 8 5 37174378 sda5 8 6 36964352 sda6 8 16 31696896 sdb 8 17 31695872 sdb1

here sda is my hdd and sdb is my pendrive attached

now use "mount /dev/sda1 /mnt "

now move into the partion mounted using command "cd /mnt " and now do " ls " and this ls will list all your files and you can know weather you have linux installed or not using some file structure . eg when i do ls i get like this :

bin patches {bin,sbin,conf,samples} proc boot root cdrom run config sbin data selinux debug setup dev share doc src etc srv home sys initrd.img tmp lib usr

so if you have similar file structuer then this is your partion where you have linux installed in hdd

if not then do "sudo umount /dev/sda1" and then do "sudo mount /dev/sda2" etc like this try all your partions untill you see your files

so now you got to know your partion where the ubuntu is already install in you haddisk , say ex the hard disk is sda2

now do there comands to mount the proc and sys dirs,

sudo mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev sudo chroot /mnt "{you have gone into chroot env now you have to mount proc and sys"}

mount -t proc none /proc mount -t sysfs none /sys mount -t devpts none /dev/pts

```
Now, you will get command-like access to the installed Ubuntu's shell There you can try sudo apt-get install "linux kernel headers pkg name" sudo apt-get install build-essentials
```

once you have install exit chroot

by just typing exit

then reboot the machine and remove the live os to boot into your OS

Comment: Thanks for answer. But as you see from question category i am new in linux. could you please write instructions/commands clearly please.

Comment: check the edited answer